# Trouble adding item to the ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Working on a Crazy Eights game for my Grade 12 computer science class. I want to add a card from the `Deck` class to the `Pile` class. The adding the card and removing the card works fine, but how do I add that card back to the `Deck` class? When trying to do `deck.add(card);` it doesn't add the card back to the `Deck` ArrayList.

Here's the code that I have:

Game.java:

```
public class game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Deck deck = new Deck();

        deck.shuffle();

        Player player1 = new Player("Chris");
        Player player2 = new Player("Emily");


        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            player1.deck.addCard(deck.removeCard());
            player2.deck.addCard(deck.removeCard());
        }

        player1.orderCardsInHandByValue();
        player1.orderCardsInHandBySuit();


        Pile pile = new Pile();

        pile.deck.addCard(deck.removeCard());
        System.out.println("************************");
        System.out.println(pile.getTopCard());

        System.out.println("************************");
        deck.showDeck();

        pile.deck.addCard(deck.removeCard());
        System.out.println("************************");
        System.out.println(pile.getTopCard());
    }

}
```

Card.java:

```
class Card {
    private int value = 0;
    private String suit = null;

    public Card(int value, String suit) {
        this.value = value;
        this.suit = suit;
    }

    int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    String getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return (this.getSuit() + " " + this.getValue());
    }
}
```

Player.java:

```
class Player {
    private String name = null;

    Deck deck = new Deck();

    public Player(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.deck.clear();
    }

    void orderCardsInHandByValue() {
        Card temp = null;
        for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
            for (int j = i; j > 0; j--) {
                if(this.deck.get(j).getValue() < this.deck.get(j - 1).getValue()) {
                    temp = this.deck.get(j);
                    this.deck.set(j, this.deck.get(j - 1));
                    this.deck.set(j - 1, temp);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void orderCardsInHandBySuit() {
        Card temp = null;
        for(int i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
            for(int j = i; j > 0; j--) {
                if(this.deck.get(j).getSuit().compareTo(this.deck.get(j - 1).getSuit()) < 0) {
                    temp = this.deck.get(j);
                    this.deck.set(j, this.deck.get(j - 1));
                    this.deck.set(j - 1, temp);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Pile.java (this is the class that I'm having problems trying to add the card given to the `Pile` class back to the `Deck` class. The pile class is used to grab the top card from the deck.):

```
class Pile extends Deck {

    Deck deck = new Deck();
    Card card = null;

    public Pile() {
        this.deck.clear();
    }

    Card getTopCard() {
        card = this.deck.get(0);
        this.deck.remove(0);
        deck.addCard(card);
        return card;
    }
}
```

Deck.java:

```
class Deck extends ArrayList<Card> {
    private String[] suits = {"Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"};
    private String[] ranks = {"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "1"};

    public Deck() {
        for (int i = 0; i < ranks.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < suits.length; j++) {
                this.add(new Card(Integer.parseInt(ranks[i]), suits[j]));
            }
        }
    }

    void shuffle() {
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 52 - 1; i++) {
            int randomValue = i + random.nextInt(52 - i);
            Card card = this.get(i);
            this.set(i, this.get(randomValue));
            this.set(randomValue, card);
        }
    }

    void showDeck() {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(this.get(i));
        }
    }

    void clearDeck()
    {
        this.clear();
    }

    Card addCard(Card cardToAdd) {
        this.add(cardToAdd);
        return cardToAdd;
    }

    Card removeCard() {
        Card card = (Card) this.get(0);
        this.remove(0);
        return card;
    }
}
```

My code doesn't have a good design, mostly because I have to follow certain requirements my teacher has set out.

Comment: I wouldn't be extending `ArrayList` - if this is a requirement from your teacher, they are wrong and shouldn't be teaching

Comment: Also, your code doesn't compile, `card.face`, `Card` doesn't have a `face` method (or a `clear` method)

Comment: `deck.add(card)` should be `deck.addCard(card)`

Comment: ^--- Is one of the many reasons why you should avoid extending `ArrayList`

Comment: @MadProgrammer My mistake. I forgot to remove the `void deal()` function. It should work fine now.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I edited my post. I added a `toString` function to the `Card` class and added the line of code `deck.addCard(card)` to my `Pile` class. However, my code still doesn't work as I want it to.

Comment: If you are using an IDE, can you set a breakpoint and check the state of `pile` when you call `getTopCard()`?

Comment: `Pile` extends `Deck`. Why a `Deck` instance is used inside `Pile`? You have made it confusing for yourself and struggling. Looks like you are confused between `Pile.deck` and the deck contents of `Pile` instance inherited by extending `Deck`. Cleanup your design.

Answer (score 1):

This...

```
class Pile extends Deck {

    Deck deck = new Deck();
```

and this...

```
class Deck extends ArrayList<Card> {
```

are confusing everybody.

There is simply no reason for either.  A `Pile` is a instance of `Deck`, so you don't actually need a seperate class, just create an instance of `Deck` and call it a "pile"

Extending `ArrayList` is ill-advised. You're not add any "additional" functionality to the class (which doesn't already exists in the base class) and it's just causing you confusion, as you keep calling methods of the `ArrayList` and the new class which do the same functionality (which is why `Pile` is so screwed up)

So, if instead, we get rid of `Pile` and make `Deck` a container for `ArrayList`, we get something which looks more like...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Deck deck = new Deck();

        deck.shuffle();

        Player player1 = new Player("Chris");
        Player player2 = new Player("Emily");

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            player1.deck.addCard(deck.popToCard());
            player2.deck.addCard(deck.popToCard());
        }

        player1.orderCardsInHandByValue();
        player1.orderCardsInHandBySuit();

        Deck pile = new Deck();
        pile.clearDeck();

        for (int index = 0; index < 2; index++) {
            Card popped = deck.popToCard();
            pile.addCard(popped);
            System.out.println("Popped " + popped + " from deck, added to pile");
            System.out.println("Pile's top card = " + pile.getTopCard());

            System.out.println("Deck contains...");
            deck.showDeck();
            System.out.println("...Deck contains");

            System.out.println("Pile contains...");
            pile.showDeck();
            System.out.println("...Pile contains");
        }
    }

    static class Card {

        private int value = 0;
        private String suit = null;

        public Card(int value, String suit) {
            this.value = value;
            this.suit = suit;
        }

        int getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        String getSuit() {
            return suit;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return (this.getValue() + " of " + this.getSuit());
        }
    }

    static class Player {

        private String name = null;

        Deck deck = new Deck();

        public Player(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            this.deck.clearDeck();
        }

        void orderCardsInHandByValue() {
            Card temp = null;
            for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
                for (int j = i; j > 0; j--) {
                    if (this.deck.get(j).getValue() < this.deck.get(j - 1).getValue()) {
                        temp = this.deck.get(j);
                        this.deck.set(j, this.deck.get(j - 1));
                        this.deck.set(j - 1, temp);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        void orderCardsInHandBySuit() {
            Card temp = null;
            for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
                for (int j = i; j > 0; j--) {
                    if (this.deck.get(j).getSuit().compareTo(this.deck.get(j - 1).getSuit()) < 0) {
                        temp = this.deck.get(j);
                        this.deck.set(j, this.deck.get(j - 1));
                        this.deck.set(j - 1, temp);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static class Deck {

        private String[] suits = {"Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"};
        private String[] ranks = {"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "1"};

        private ArrayList<Card> cards;

        public Deck() {
            cards = new ArrayList<>(52);
            for (int i = 0; i < ranks.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < suits.length; j++) {
                    cards.add(new Card(Integer.parseInt(ranks[i]), suits[j]));
                }
            }
        }

        void shuffle() {
            Collections.shuffle(cards);
//          Random random = new Random();
//          for (int i = 0; i < 52 - 1; i++) {
//              int randomValue = i + random.nextInt(52 - i);
//              Card card = this.get(i);
//              this.set(i, this.get(randomValue));
//              this.set(randomValue, card);
//          }
        }

        void showDeck() {
            for (Card card : cards) {
                System.out.println("\t" + card);
            }
        }

        void clearDeck() {
            cards.clear();
        }

        Card addCard(Card cardToAdd) {
            cards.add(cardToAdd);
            return cardToAdd;
        }

        Card popToCard() {
            return cards.remove(0);
        }

        public Card get(int index) {
            return cards.get(index);
        }

        public Card getTopCard() {
            return cards.get(0);
        }

        public void set(int index, Card card) {
            cards.set(index, card);
        }
    }

}
```

And which outputs something like...

```
Popped 4 of Spades from deck, added to pile
Pile's top card = 4 of Spades
Deck contains...
    10 of Diamonds
    1 of Spades
    // Lots of cards, removed for brevity 
...Deck contains
Pile contains...
    4 of Spades
...Pile contains
Popped 10 of Diamonds from deck, added to pile
Pile's top card = 4 of Spades
Deck contains...
    1 of Spades
    // Lots of cards, removed for brevity 
...Deck contains
Pile contains...
    4 of Spades
    10 of Diamonds
...Pile contains
```

> I originally wrote the Deck class without extending ArrayList and created a private ArrayList variable. However, my teacher told me to do it his way which is what I have shown you here. The Deck constructor, that was done by my teacher, not me. I can't discard the Pile class because it is part of the design map my teacher told me I had to follow. The design map has five classes. Deck is the parent class, followed by Pile as the child class. Card class and Player class do not extend/implement/inherit anything from Deck or Pile. Game class is the class with the main function.

I stand by my previous statement, but since we have no choice, as arguing with a teacher stuck in there ways is like arguing with a client who has no technical expertise

```
public class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Game();
    }

    public Game() {
        Deck deck = new Deck();

        deck.shuffle();

        Player player1 = new Player("Chris");
        Player player2 = new Player("Emily");

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            player1.deck.add(deck.popTopCard());
            player2.deck.add(deck.popTopCard());
        }

        player1.orderCardsInHandByValue();
        player1.orderCardsInHandBySuit();

        Pile pile = new Pile();

        for (int index = 0; index < 4; index++) {
            System.out.println("Deck:");
            deck.showDeck();
            System.out.println("Pile:");
            pile.showDeck();

            Card popped = deck.popTopCard();
            pile.add(popped);
            System.out.println("\nPopped " + popped + " from deck, added to pile");
        }
        System.out.println("Deck:");
        deck.showDeck();
        System.out.println("Pile:");
        pile.showDeck();
    }

    class Deck extends ArrayList<Card> {

        private String[] suits = {"Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"};
        private String[] ranks = {"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "1"};

        public Deck() {
            for (int i = 0; i < ranks.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < suits.length; j++) {
                    this.add(new Card(Integer.parseInt(ranks[i]), suits[j]));
                }
            }
        }

        void shuffle() {
            Collections.shuffle(this);
        }

        void showDeck() {
            for (int i = 0; i < this.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println("\t" + this.get(i));
            }
        }

        public Card popTopCard() {
            if (isEmpty()) {
                return null;
            }
            return remove(0);
        }

        public Card peekTopCard() {
            if (isEmpty()) {
                return null;
            }
            return get(0);
        }

    }

    class Pile extends Deck {

        public Pile() {
            this.clear();
        }
    }

    class Card {

        private int value = 0;
        private String suit = null;

        public Card(int value, String suit) {
            this.value = value;
            this.suit = suit;
        }

        int getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        String getSuit() {
            return suit;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return (this.getSuit() + " " + this.getValue());
        }
    }

    class Player {

        private String name = null;

        Deck deck = new Deck();

        public Player(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            this.deck.clear();
        }

        void orderCardsInHandByValue() {
            Card temp = null;
            for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
                for (int j = i; j > 0; j--) {
                    if (this.deck.get(j).getValue() < this.deck.get(j - 1).getValue()) {
                        temp = this.deck.get(j);
                        this.deck.set(j, this.deck.get(j - 1));
                        this.deck.set(j - 1, temp);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        void orderCardsInHandBySuit() {
            Card temp = null;
            for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
                for (int j = i; j > 0; j--) {
                    if (this.deck.get(j).getSuit().compareTo(this.deck.get(j - 1).getSuit()) < 0) {
                        temp = this.deck.get(j);
                        this.deck.set(j, this.deck.get(j - 1));
                        this.deck.set(j - 1, temp);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which outputs something like...

```
Deck:
    Clubs 4
    Diamonds 3
    Hearts 4
    Clubs 12
    Hearts 2
    Hearts 9
    Spades 12
    Clubs 6
    Spades 4
    Hearts 6
    Clubs 7
    Diamonds 8
    Spades 8
    Diamonds 7
    Hearts 7
    Hearts 10
    Diamonds 11
    Spades 7
    Clubs 3
    Spades 10
    Clubs 1
    Spades 3
    Clubs 5
    Spades 1
    Diamonds 9
    Clubs 10
    Spades 13
    Hearts 11
    Clubs 13
    Clubs 9
    Spades 11
    Hearts 13
    Hearts 5
    Hearts 12
    Spades 2
    Clubs 11
Pile:
Popped Clubs 4 from deck, added to pile
Deck:
    Diamonds 3
    Hearts 4
    Clubs 12
    Hearts 2
    Hearts 9
    Spades 12
    Clubs 6
    Spades 4
    Hearts 6
    Clubs 7
    Diamonds 8
    Spades 8
    Diamonds 7
    Hearts 7
    Hearts 10
    Diamonds 11
    Spades 7
    Clubs 3
    Spades 10
    Clubs 1
    Spades 3
    Clubs 5
    Spades 1
    Diamonds 9
    Clubs 10
    Spades 13
    Hearts 11
    Clubs 13
    Clubs 9
    Spades 11
    Hearts 13
    Hearts 5
    Hearts 12
    Spades 2
    Clubs 11
Pile:
    Clubs 4
Popped Diamonds 3 from deck, added to pile
Deck:
    Hearts 4
    Clubs 12
    Hearts 2
    Hearts 9
    Spades 12
    Clubs 6
    Spades 4
    Hearts 6
    Clubs 7
    Diamonds 8
    Spades 8
    Diamonds 7
    Hearts 7
    Hearts 10
    Diamonds 11
    Spades 7
    Clubs 3
    Spades 10
    Clubs 1
    Spades 3
    Clubs 5
    Spades 1
    Diamonds 9
    Clubs 10
    Spades 13
    Hearts 11
    Clubs 13
    Clubs 9
    Spades 11
    Hearts 13
    Hearts 5
    Hearts 12
    Spades 2
    Clubs 11
Pile:
    Clubs 4
    Diamonds 3
Popped Hearts 4 from deck, added to pile
Deck:
    Clubs 12
    Hearts 2
    Hearts 9
    Spades 12
    Clubs 6
    Spades 4
    Hearts 6
    Clubs 7
    Diamonds 8
    Spades 8
    Diamonds 7
    Hearts 7
    Hearts 10
    Diamonds 11
    Spades 7
    Clubs 3
    Spades 10
    Clubs 1
    Spades 3
    Clubs 5
    Spades 1
    Diamonds 9
    Clubs 10
    Spades 13
    Hearts 11
    Clubs 13
    Clubs 9
    Spades 11
    Hearts 13
    Hearts 5
    Hearts 12
    Spades 2
    Clubs 11
Pile:
    Clubs 4
    Diamonds 3
    Hearts 4
Popped Clubs 12 from deck, added to pile
Deck:
    Hearts 2
    Hearts 9
    Spades 12
    Clubs 6
    Spades 4
    Hearts 6
    Clubs 7
    Diamonds 8
    Spades 8
    Diamonds 7
    Hearts 7
    Hearts 10
    Diamonds 11
    Spades 7
    Clubs 3
    Spades 10
    Clubs 1
    Spades 3
    Clubs 5
    Spades 1
    Diamonds 9
    Clubs 10
    Spades 13
    Hearts 11
    Clubs 13
    Clubs 9
    Spades 11
    Hearts 13
    Hearts 5
    Hearts 12
    Spades 2
    Clubs 11
Pile:
    Clubs 4
    Diamonds 3
    Hearts 4
    Clubs 12
```

Comment: I originally wrote the `Deck` class without extending ArrayList and created a private ArrayList variable. However, my teacher told me to do it his way which is what I have shown you here. The `Deck` constructor, that was done by my teacher, not me. I can't discard the Pile class because it is part of the design map my teacher told me I had to follow. The design map has five classes. `Deck` is the parent class, followed by `Pile` as the child class. `Card` class and `Player` class do not extend/implement/inherit anything from `Deck` or `Pile`. `Game` class is the class with the main function.

Comment: He's making our whole class follow these outrageous rules. I'm seriously having trouble writing the code for the Pile class. The project was due last Friday and everyone in my class is handing in let because everyone is struggling with finishing this project.

Comment: How do I add those cards in the `Pile` class back to the original `Deck` once I'm doing using them. Also, the `popTopCard` function has to be in the `Pile` class. The `Pile` class is used to retrieve the top card from the deck and return it to the players. Once I return the card to the players, I need to put that card back in the deck so I don't run out of cards to play with.

Comment: Take the cards from the pile and put them into the deck (look for addAll)